# Screen Sharing not Available in my HP Laptop

Tags: 22.04, screen, sharing

On my HP lap, I can't find an option called screen sharing on the latest ver 22.04. I have an option called remote desktop, and that is not discovered by other device. Can any one help by giving suggestion for mirroring my lap on smart TV ? I am not interested in sharing using by chrome cast or like options.

Comment: How is it you expect the TV to receive the signal from the computer?

Comment: I have watched a video on youtube, showing my request. I can't see such a setting in my laptop. In that video, he describes how to mirror linux based laptop mirroring as setting-sharing-screen sharing. But I see is setting-sharing-remote desktop. This is what I am talking about.

Comment: Are you sure the video used Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: No, am not sure, but I have to share my laptop on smart TV  as he done

Comment: I understand what you want to do but that does not change that the video may not have been for this version of Ubuntu and does not apply here.